# How to combine(iterate through) 2 strings, mixing the letters in each string with different length?

Tags: javascript, loops

EDIT: the output should be t1h2i3s4oneislong

I am trying to write a function which returns a new word,combining the letters in 2 words which are being passed the function. If word1 is hello and word2 is 12345 it should return h1e2l3l4o5 - mixing all the letters of both words. The problem is that if one word is longer than the other one, I get undefinedundefinedundefined etc.

I thought I could just ask is word1.length

Could someone explain why this doesn't work (I am learning) and how I could make it work? Thank you!!

```
function creatingWord(one,two){
 var string="";
 if (one.length==1 &&two.length==1){
 string=one+two;
}
else if (one.length==two.length){
    for (var i=0; i<one.length;i++){
        string+=one[i];
        string+=two[i];
   }
}
else if (one.length>two.length){
   for (var j=0; j<one.length;j++){
    string+=one[j];
    string+=two[j];
    }
}
return string;
}


var result = creatingWord('thisoneislong', '1234');
result;
```

Comment: What is the expected output if one word is longer than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two possible answers here, depending on what you want the output to be.

This code gives you the output "t1h2i3s4oneislong" (continuing with the longer word once the other is exhausted):

```
function creatingWord(one, two){
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(one.length, two.length); i++) {
    if (one.length > i) {
        output += one[i];
    }
    if (two.length > i) {
        output += two[i];
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Here's a version that gives the output "t1h2i3s4" (truncates to the smaller word):

```
function creatingWord(one, two){
  var output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(one.length, two.length); i++) {
    output += one[i] + two[i];
  }
  return output;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Answering a comment below, here's a version that takes a variable number of arguments:

```
// takes a variable number of words
function creatingWord() {
  var output = "";
  var words = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  var maxLength = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i];
    if (word.length > maxLength) {
      maxLength = word.length;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
      var word = words[j];
      if (word.length > i) {
        output += word[i];
      }
    }
  }

  return output;
}
```

Comment: And possibly a third (or fourth), resulting in (eg.): "t1his2o3neislo4ng".

Comment: @user2864740 That hadn't occurred to me, but yes, maybe some sort of "spread the characters out" thing is desired? We'll need clarification on the desired output.

Comment: Thank you, your code works! can you explain (as I am learning and trying to understand whats happening) , what was happening in my code? I thought that if I 'ask' which word is the longest and then iterate through the longest, it would just keep adding the letters-why was this not happening?

Comment: Your two "else if"s have exactly the same code in them (just using a different variable name), so I'm really not sure what you were trying to do there. The reason you're seeing "undefined" getting appended to the string is because you're walking past the end of the string. `"foo"[8]` will give you `undefined`.

Comment: "Your two "else if"s have exactly the same code in them" - you are right, in the second else statement I thought-if I make sure I iterate through the longer string, i won't get undefined because- thisoneislong- is the longest one (13 characters) so it would be i<13, meaning that all the characters should be added?!

Comment: also I was wondering, if the function is passed more arguments (more than 2) - I thought I could do this:  var args=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.max.apply(null,args); i++) { etc. however it doesn't work?!

Comment: See edit. Your `Math.max` call doesn't make sense... you're saying "What's the maximum of this list of strings?" But what you want is "What's the maximum of the lengths of each string in this list of strings?"

Answer (score 0):

You can split your words to work with Array functions like `reduce()`, code looks cleaner :

```js
let a = 'HelloWorld';
let b = '_____';

let combineWords = (a,b) => b.split('') && 
  a.split('').reduce((prev, curr, i)=> prev += curr + (b[i] || ''),'');

console.log(combineWords(a, b));
console.log(combineWords(b, a));
```

Note that `combineWords(a, b)` will return all the posible combinations attending to `a.length`

Answer (score 0):

Using the length of the first word as the output length, we can use the following to combine any list of words as stated in your question:

```js
var zip = array => array[0].map((a, i) => array.map(a => a[i]));

var words = ["aaaa", "bbb", "cc", "d", "........"],
    combined = zip(words.map(w => w.split(""))).map(a => a.join("")).join("");

console.log(combined); // abcd.abc.ab.a.
```